# How can I copy a sharepoint online site plus content to a new site collection using native microsoft tools?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I copy a SharePoint online site plus content to a new site collection using native Microsoft tools i.e. SharePoint/PowerShell/

PLEASE NOTE I ONLY HAVE SITE COLLECTION ADMIN RIGHTS - I DO NOT HAVE SHAREPOINT ADMIN AT M365 LEVEL.